# Can glReadPixels be used to read layers from GL_TEXTURE_3D?

Tags: opengl, textures, fbo

I'm trying to read a 3D texture I rendered using an FBO. This texture is so large that `glGetTexImage` results in `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error due to failure of `nvidia` driver to allocate memory for intermediate storage<sup>*</sup> (needed, I suppose, to avoid changing destination buffer in case of error).

So I then thought of getting this texture layer by layer, using `glReadPixels` after I render each layer. But `glReadPixels` doesn't have layer index as a parameter. The only place where it actually appears as something that directs I/O to the particular layer is `gl_Layer` output in the geometry shader. And that is for the writing stage, not reading.

As I tried simply doing the calls to `glReadPixels` anyway after I render each layer, I only got the texels for layer 0. So `glReadPixels` at least doesn't fail to get *something*.

But the question is: can I get arbitrary layer of a 3D texture using `glReadPixels`? And if not, what should I use instead, given the above described memory constraints? Do I have to sample the layer from 3D texture in a shader to render the result to a 2D texture, and read *this 2D texture* afterwards?

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>It's not a guess, I've actually tracked it down to a failing `malloc` call (with the size of the texture as argument) from within the nvidia driver's shared library.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `glReadPixels` can read other slices from the 3D texture. One just has to use `glFramebufferTextureLayer` to attach the correct current slice to the FBO — instead of attaching the full 3D texture as the color attachment. Here's the replacement code for `glGetTexImage` (a special FBO for this, `fboForTextureSaving`, should be generated beforehand):

```
GLint origReadFramebuffer=0, origDrawFramebuffer=0;
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &origReadFramebuffer);
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &origDrawFramebuffer);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboForTextureSaving);
for(int layer=0; layer<depth; ++layer)
{
    gl.glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                                 texture, 0, layer);
    checkFramebufferStatus("framebuffer for saving textures");
    gl.glReadPixels(0,0,w,h,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT, subpixels+layer*w*h*4);
}
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, origReadFramebuffer);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, origDrawFramebuffer);
```

---

Anyway, this is not a long-term solution to the problem. The first reason for `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` errors with large textures is actually not lack of RAM or VRAM. It's subtler: each texture allocated on GPU is mapped to the process' address space (at least on Linux/`nvidia`). So if your process doesn't `malloc` even half of the RAM available to it, its address space may be already used by these large mappings. Add to this a bit of memory fragmentation, and you get either `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`, or `malloc` failure, or `std::bad_alloc` somewhere even earlier than expected.

The proper long-term solution is to embrace the 64-bit reality and compile your app as 64-bit code. This is what I ended up doing, ditching all this layer-by-layer kludge and simplifying the code quite a bit.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to GL 4.5 or ARB_get_texture_sub_image, you can employ [`glGetTextureSubImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTextureSubImage.xhtml). As the function name suggests, it's for querying a sub-section of a texture's image data. This allows you to read slices of the texture without having to get the whole thing in one go.

The extension seems [fairly widely supported](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image), available on any implementation that's still being supported by its IHV.

Comment: This extension gave me hope... until I tried and saw the reality. Yes, it is supported almost everywhere. But it appears that Linux `nvidia` driver on GTX 750Ti gets the whole texture when a call is made as `glGetTextureSubImage(texture,0, 0,0,z, w,h,1, GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT, w*h*4*sizeof subpixels[0], subpixels+z*w*h*4);`, and only copies the data from the intermediate `malloc`'ed storage to the destination buffer. So I get the same failures as with `glGetTexImage`.

Answer (score 0):

So once you got your 3D texture you can do this:

```
for (z=0;z<z_resolution_of_your_txr;z++)
 {
 render_textured_quad(using z slice of 3D texture);
 glReadPixels(...);
 }
```

Its best to match the QUAD size ot your 3D texture x,y resolutions and use `GL_NEAREST` filtering...

This will be slow so if you are not on Intel and want to be more fast you can use render to 2D Texture instead and use `glGetTexImage` on the target 2D texture instead of `glReadPixels`.

**Here example shaders for rendering slice z:**

**Vertex:**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 420 core
//------------------------------------------------------------------
uniform float aspect;
layout(location=0) in vec2 pos;

out smooth vec2 vpos;
//------------------------------------------------------------------
void main(void)
    {
    vpos=pos;
    gl_Position=vec4(pos.x,pos.y*aspect,0.0,1.0);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Fragment:**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 420 core
//------------------------------------------------------------------
uniform float slice=0.25;       // <0,1> slice of txr
in smooth vec2      vpos;
uniform sampler3D   vol_txr;    // 3D texture unit used
out layout(location=0) vec4 frag_col;
void main()
    {
    frag_col=texture(vol_txr,vec3(0.5*(vpos+1.0),slice));
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So you need to change the slice uniform before each slice render. The rendering itself is just single QUAD covering the screen <-1,+1> while viewport matches the texture x,y resolution...

Comment: As I said in the OP, this exact loop gives me the data from the slice 0 on each iteration.

Comment: @Ruslan then you are not rendering correctly what are you using to extract the 3D texture texels?

Comment: I _am_ rendering correctly: when I have lower resolution so that `glGetTexImage` doesn't fail, it returns the expected data, while `glReadPixels` always returns data for slice 0.

Comment: @Ruslan You misunderstood ... glReadPixels is obtaining data from rendered frame buffer not from texture. So you need to render the texture slice first if that is not done properly the fetched data will also be not good... show the rendering code

Comment: Well, the rendering code is basically what you suggest: `for(unsigned layer=0; layer<texDepth; ++layer) { program.setUniformValue("layer",layer);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
glReadPixels(0,0,texWidth,texHeight,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,pixelsToSave+layer*texWidth*texHeight*4);
}`

Comment: Well I did have the slice uniform. In the comment above it's the `"layer"` uniform, which gets written into `gl_Layer` in the geometry shader.

Comment: @Ruslan I added shaders that works on mine 3D textures ... You can even change the slice into z coordinate of the Vertex data ... but I would need to rewrite much more code to test such shaders ... The shaders works liek a sharm visually

Comment: @Ruslan did you turned off the `GL_DEPTH_TEST` and `GL_CULL_FACE` ? If not `glClear` might also help with the depth ...

Comment: I never had them, and anyway, that's irrelevant: `glGetTexImage` works fine when it has enough memory, so the rendering result is correct.

Comment: @Ruslan its not irrelevant if you want to use `glReadPixels` ... because depth test on might prohibit you to render any other layer after the first one is rendered.... Cull face might throw away all rendered layers if wrong polygon winding ... Also are you rendering to screen or to invisible FrameBuffer ?

Comment: How can depth test interfere here if the difference is only between two ways of reading? One of the ways works correctly, while the other doesn't. I am rendering to texture, not to screen.

Comment: @Ruslan its not interfering with the glReadPixels itself but with the rendering instead

Comment: But rendering is correct, as `glGetTexImage` gives the expected result.

Comment: @Ruslan that is hardly a proof more of the opposite as `glGetTexImage` is copying data from texture and not from rendered Framebuffer so it has nothing to do with rendering. So if `glReadPixels` is not OK and `glGetTexImage` is it means that most likely the rendering is not OK. You can visually check by seeing the rendered layer ... if it is any different than the first one

Comment: I still don't get it. How can I have rendered the whole 3D texture using the FBO correctly (so that `glGetTexImage` gets correct values in all layers), yet have the FBO contents (which are backed by the texture!) wrong (so that `glReadPixels` gets wrong values)?